Is possible to delay or hold `Checkbox` state when user click the Checkbox
I have one Checkbox, when user click the Checkbox then I do call http request to API. But the state of this Checkbox base on result the API.
The problem is when user don't have data internet or connection, the Checkbox still checked so I must handle to uncheck the Checkbox. Is there way to delay or hold the state check of Checkbox?
I use onClickListener like below :
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(requireActivity());
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
        callAPI(); // if fails then I must do manually uncheck the checkbox
    });


you can store state as boolean value as local variable and check/uncheck based on the value

yes my current code did that. So I must save every state on my CheckBox. But my question is can I do hold the state instead save that state then restore

CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(requireActivity());

checkBox.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();

    // Simply disable the checkbox so it cant be clicked again.
    checkBox.setEnabled(false);

    // Make your api call. I am using a callback function because IDK what your actual implementation is.
    // But remember to store the previous state like i did with `isChecked` so you can revert it if the api call fails.
    callAPI(isChecked, success -> {
        if (success) {
            // Enable the checkbox again.
            checkBox.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            // It failed, revert the checked state and enable the checkbox.
            checkBox.setChecked(!isChecked);
            checkBox.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
});

Happy New Year!
